# Can't make query after session expired

Tags: php, sql, facebook, session

I've binged a lot for this stuff, but couldn't find direct ANSWER,
I've searched for this here,

But
I am still beating my head against the wall trying to implement,

How do I do update query after session expired? 
I'm not talking about explicit clicking "Logout" button

Here's basic SQL structure:

```
CREATE TABLE auth_users (

 email       varchar(40) NOT NULL,
 password    varchar(40) NOT NULL,
 online      ENUM('1') DEFAULT NULL  <-- HERE, it updates to 1 when user logged in, it updates back to NULL when user explicitly clicks on LOGOUT

) type=MyISAM;
```

Class Hierarchy:

```
interface {
    function login();
    function logout();
        //calls after succes authorization
        function set_as_online();
        //calls from within logout() method
        function set_as_offline();
}
```

BUT IT DOES NOT UPDATES BACK TO NULL WHEN USER CLOSES HIS BROWSER,

For example, 
Assume we have two users: User-A, User-B

User A logged successfully, now User-B can see User-A as ONLINE user.

If User-A forget to click "LOGOUT" and would close his browser,
user-B still can see User-A as ONLINE. That's the problem.

For example,
Facebook handles this very well,

Assume your friend just closed the browser (i.e his session does not exists anymore),
then somehow you can see him as OFFLINE

What am I doing wrong? Incorrect approach of handling offline/online users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach is needed here i think. Don't set a online/offline flag, but a 'last_seen' timestamp. Ie. with every request update the record to the current timestamp. If you want to know if the user is online, just do:

```
if($current_time - $last_seen_time < $session_expire_limit) {
    // online
} else {
    // offline
}
```

Otherwise you'd need a cronjob of some sort to automatically reset the `online` flag in your database after a certain time, but then still you'd need a `last_seen` column.

// edit

i don't know exactly how facebook does it, but it *could* be one of the following; for the chat and notify functionality facebook opens up a 'stream', which is in fact a little ajax call which is kept alive by the server (btw, this ajax call is refreshed every 40 seconds). Possibly this stream is used to track online users. Another option, but less likely, is that an event is attached to the window.unload event. This is less likely because a page refresh, a clicked link to another facebook page etc. is also triggering the event. This would mean that every time an internal facebook link is clicked the event should be unbinded from the browser.
Can't think of another way atm, just some suggestions. Unfortunately those are quite labor-heavy to implement, I assume my suggestion above (before the edit) should be suitable for a common website.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how facebook controls this stuff but i can suggest you from the top of my head how i would approach this matter.

I would add a new field on your auth_users table of type Date that will represent the session_expiry_time .

Then inside your html pages you should implement some silent ajax code that will call a dummy php page on the server (the interval is something very important because you have to balance performance and functionality). This dummy page will update the session_expiry_time of the user in 
the auth_users table.

Therefore, in any given time, checking a user's session_expiry_time against current time will determine if the user is online or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple JavaScript on the page

In the body tag

The callLogoff() should be replaced with the JavaScript function that calls log off.

Try it.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php
you can with register_shutdown_function() und connection_aborted() your intend achieve

Comment: those php functions are not meant for that and not usable at all. They online keep track of the connection status of your script itself, but once the html is served, there is no connection anymore; which means, your user would only be 'online' for a second or two when your page is loading, but once the user is looking at things, he would be 'offline'. But in this case, that would only start a user being online (when the first page loads that is)...